# Google Analytics. Force root domain to show as "external"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website on a subdomain: sub.main.com which has nothing in common with the root domain "main.com".

When I try to view the referrals from the root domain - it isn't there.Somehow Google doesn't include it in referrals report, presumably because it's a root domain of my website. Is there a way to force Google Analytics to count the root domain as an external one?

Comment: Look in the property settings - if your domain is in the referral exclusion list you should remove it.

Comment: Thanks, man, you saved my day. Dunno how the root domain wound up in the exclusion list, but it was there, I removed it and now we are rolling.

Comment: It's added automatically when you create a new Universal Analytics Account - mostly people try to avoid self-referalls, so that's the default setting.